# $x+\frac{1}{x}\leq - 2$ for $x<0$?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

I did a similar one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877514/prove-the-inequality-x-frac1x-geq-2). So I guess that to prove this one, we just need:

$$x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$$

As $x>0$ implies that $x+\frac{1}{x}$ is positive, then if $x<0$ then $x+\frac{1}{x}$ is the sum of two negative numbers and hence, negative. Then we just need to multiply both sides by $-1$:

$$-x-\frac{1}{x}\leq -2$$

As $x<0$, we can write:

$$x+\frac{1}{x}\leq -2$$

I'm not sure if I messed up something.

Comment: It's an odd function, so..

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Substitute $z = -x$. $\displaystyle -z - \frac1{z} \le -2$ , $-z < 0$ which becomes  $\displaystyle z + \frac1{z} \ge 2$ , $z > 0$

Answer (score 1):

I think you proceeded right . other way round you can explain it this way- let x<0  let t= -x where t>0  so  t + 1/t > or = 2 so.   -x + -1/x > or =2  hence x +1/x

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is nice. You can also derive it like you did $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$, by assuming $x$ is negative:

$$ (x+1)^2 \ge 0$$

$$x^2 + 2x + 1 \ge 0$$

$$x^2 + 1 \ge -2x$$

$$x+\dfrac 1x \le -2$$